# Python Selenium, move a interactive map (canvas) by a specific pixel value

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My aim is to open the website that shows an interactive map that you can move/drag and then; jump to a specific location; take a screenshot and then move the map so I can take a Screenshot raster to create one bigger picture.

I'm not able to drag the map, everything else works fine. I also managed to do normal drag-and-drop operations with selenium. But something seems to be special about that map because it's not an image that you move. Maybe I'm just using the wrong CSS_Selector or/and XPath, but I tried all. I would be so glad if anyone could help me out with that.

Here is my code, In the last section I try to move/drag the map, but I will show you the whole code I had came up with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
import base64


from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.geoportal-bw.de/#/(sidenav:karten)")
driver.maximize_window()

sleep(4)

def search_place():
    
    place_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/cv-layout/div/div/div/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/div/gp-search-slot/mat-form-field/div/div[1]/div[3]/input")
    place_input.send_keys("Emmendingen")
    sleep(3)
    
    
    
    #searching for a specific region where to start
    search_result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/cv-layout/div/div/div/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav/div/gp-search-results/div/div/mat-list/gp-search-result-places/gp-search-result-place[1]/mat-list-item/span")
    search_result.click()
    sleep(2)
    
    #zoom to a specific scale that is needed (zoom+ button)
    zoom_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/cv-layout/div/div/div/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/div/div/fg-mapcontrols-zoom/div/button[1]")
    zoom_button.click()
    sleep(1)
    zoom_button.click()
    
    sleep(5)
    
    #Screenshot of canvas
    
    
    canvas = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ol-map > div > div.ol-unselectable.ol-layers > div > canvas")

    # get the canvas as a PNG base64 string
    canvas_base64 = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].toDataURL('image/png').substring(21);", canvas)

    # decode
    canvas_png = base64.b64decode(canvas_base64)

    # save to a file
    with open(r"1screeni.png", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(canvas_png)

    
   
    sleep(5)
######### here I try to move the map
    
def move_canvas_element():
    canvas = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ol-map > div > div.ol-unselectable.ol-layers > div > canvas")
    
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(canvas).perform()
    action.click_and_hold().perform()
    action.move_by_offset(-100, -100).perform()
    action.release().perform()
    
    sleep(5)

# Führen Sie zuerst die Suchfunktion aus
search_place()

# Dann führen Sie die Funktion zum Bewegen des Canvas-Elements aus
move_canvas_element()
```

I tried using the XPath instead because the CSS_Selector says "unselectable..." but for the Screenshot before it also works. But anyway, XPath didn't work as well. I tried using other CSS_Selectors of other elements in the HTML Code that could be as well the map but still nothing is moving.

Comment: give: action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(canvas, -100, -100).build().perform();  a try.